# Why do we choose to use agar instead of agarose in various microbial applications?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, microbiology, gel-electrophoresis

When performing gel-electrophoresis we always use agarose. Is there a reason we can't perform it using Agar?

And in microbial culture Agar is commonly used as solidifying agent, could this be replaced with agarose.

I understand the difference in price, composition, and manufacturing but other than that how would it affect the result?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Please also note we have a [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) requirement. You could help your question  by telling us what you have found out.

Answer (score 3):

Agarose is indeed more expensive than agar because it is purified from agar, i.e. it is agar minus the agaropectin. Agaropectin is heterogeneous, and modified with acidic side-groups. The consequence of this is that it would interfere with the migration of nucleic acid in the gel.
Similarly, agarose is sometimes used for observing zones of inhibitions of growth or lysis plages of microorganisms caused some antimicrobials, because it interferes less with their diffusion than agar.